# Sublime text not recognizing unicode characters

Tags: math, unicode, sublimetext2

When I put ∃ (or various other maths characters) into Sublime Text 2 it displays a question mark in a box. It might be � but it's rendered as an upright box instead of a diamond.

I copied � into sublime text and it rendered it in the same way that it rendered ∃.

All the characters in question are rendering correctly in notepad and chrome. I'm on Windows 10 if that matters.

Is there something that I can do to make these characters display properly in Sublime Text?

Update:
As roeland pointed out the issue was that the font being used didn't contain glyphs for the characters. Apparently Unicode complete fonts are uncommon. I'm using http://czyborra.com/unifont/unifont.ttf now (the only good size is 12pt).

Comment: If you copy that character back from Sublime Text to another program, does it show up as “∃” again? I'm guessing the font used to display the text in Sublime Text doesn't contain that character.

Comment: Yes copying it back does it does show up as the original. I'll check with other fonts.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a font thing because in some fonts it renders correctly and in others it doesn't. I'm installing more fonts now to try to find one that works that is also decent.

Comment: I've found that DejaVu Sans Mono is a fairly good looking coding font with excellent Unicode coverage. It's missing a few exotic characters but I've seldom had any trouble with it. (NB. Apple's Menlo is basically the same font.)

Comment: "Apparently Unicode complete fonts are uncommon" - I should hope so. Unicode defines several hundreds of thousands characters, and only a small subset is unique enough to include in a font as "designed". The smart thing for applications is to use a font fallback stack.

Comment: DejaVu Sans Mono is a much nicer font but it doesn't contain ⟺ (iff) or ⟹ (implies).